# (Actionscript 3 noob) How do you use "continue" correctly?

Tags: actionscript-3

the thing I have to do is that I need to add a 50% alpha on 9 circle exept the fifth one, heres what I tried so far... I something missing? By the way if I replace "continue" by "break" it works perfectly.

```
function rendreAlpha(pEvt:MouseEvent)
{
    for (var i:int=1; i<=9; i+=1)
    {
        trace(i);
        this["balle" + i + "_mc"].alpha = 0.5;
        if (i == 5)
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,rendreAlpha);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` runs *after* setting the `alpha`.

Therefore, the `continue;` isn't skipping any additional code.

Answer (score 1):

`continue` will end the current iteration in your `for` loop and move to the next, skipping any actions that would occur after the continue statement for that iteration.

`break` will end the entire loop and skip any code within that iteration that occurs after it.

Here's a small demo that should help you understand both a little more clearly:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     if(i < 5)
     {
         // Skip the rest of the code in this block and move to the
         // next iteration.
         continue;
     }

     trace(i);

     if(i === 8)
     {
         // End the entire loop.
         break;
     }
}
```

You'll notice your output only includes `5,6,7 & 8`. This is because we `continue` and skip the `trace` statement in the block if `i` is less than 5, and end the loop once it hits 8.

Answer (score 0):

In flash player 10.1:

```
private static function stackDump():void
    {

        //obj can be an object, dictionary, vector, array.
        //probably anything that can be accessed using bracket notation.
        var obj:Array = [1, 2];
        var dex:int = 0;

        //if you access an object,vector,array,or dictionary using a nested incrimentor operator
        //followed by a continue statement, you will get a stack dump.
        //The loop can be a for, while, or do loop.
        while (false)
        {
            obj[dex++] = 0;
            continue;
        }

    }//end stackDump
```